# W3 CSS Validation error for font-face definition

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I have following code in my CSS file, which I think is perfectly valid, however W3C-CSS validator shows error as shown in the picture, any idea on how to fix this issue,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    url('calibri.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

See below for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add src property to font face.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    src: url('calibri.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```